# Is it correct to say "I screwed the tap onto/into the pipe"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrase-usage

[image]

I have a tap that has a male thread and a pipe that has a female thread.

Is it correct to say:

- "**I screwed the tap onto the pipe**"

or

- "**I screwed the tap into the pipe**"

In this situation ChatGPT suggests "**I screwed the tap into the pipe**"

> "I screwed the tap into the pipe": This suggests that you inserted the
> threaded end of the tap into the opening of the pipe and twisted it to
> secure it in place. It conveys the idea that the tap is now firmly
> connected and integrated with the pipe. (Chatgpt)
>
> "I screwed the tap onto the pipe": This implies that you attached the
> tap to the outside surface of the pipe, possibly using screws or other
> fasteners. It suggests that the tap is fixed to the pipe but not
> necessarily inserted into it.  (ChatGPT)

I think we can use  "**onto**" because the thread of the tap and the pipe are not important.

Comment: Have you chosen the pictures only because one is an internal (female) and the other is an external (male) thread? Or are those two exactly what you're working with?  I ask because the connector on the flexible **hose** (it is not a "pipe") is normally threaded **onto** a male thread, and so you are posing the question "backwards". Moreover, the type of thread on the tap is not compatible with the hose thread.

Comment: The flexible hose's female thread is compatible with the male thread on the *outlet* of the spigot.

Comment: @TimR, Just a random picture to express what I mean, not a real picture

Answer (score 1):

I would say you screwed it *onto* the pipe.

Screwing 'into' something could imply drilling a hole into something for a screw, or even drilling into it with the screw. Here, the pipe has a threaded end designed for the tap, so I suppose you might say it was screwed 'into' the thread, but *onto the pipe*.

I should add though that, if this is a *permanent* fixture and not some elaborate hose system, we normally use the verb *to plumb* to refer to any kind of plumbing of water systems (eg *I plumbed in a tap*).

Comment: I am wondering about a washer of some sort, or what I believe is called 'plumber's tape'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey 'Plumbing' historically meant working with lead, but modern plumbing techniques are different of course. 'Plumbed in' means it is professionally fixed in using whatever system is appropriate.

Comment: To clarify, I was semi-jocularly alluding to the possibility of leaks. I would never just put a tap on a pipe like that. Agreed that plumbing is pipe stuff, whatever the material.

Comment: into, clearly. Not onto.

Comment: @Lambie into the thread, perhaps; but *onto* the pipe.

Comment: Washers are used with hose thread, which is incompatible with pipe thread. Plumbers tape is used with pipe thread.  I've actually used the old melted lead with oakum technique when replacing a toilet flange in my house, which was built in the late 1940s, when that technique was still being used with so-called "black iron" pipe.

Comment: With the molten lead method, a short length of 4-inch pipe is placed inside the corresponding flange in the floor; a small gap between the pipe and the flange remains, like an annulus; oakum fiber is then tamped into that gap from the base of the flange to about halfway up its height, leaving space at the top for the molten lead which is poured into the gap in a single pour; the molten lead hardens rapidly as it cools yet remains malleable; a mallet and special flat chisel are then used to tamp the lead tightly into the gap all around the perimeter of the flange to form a seal.

Answer (score 0):

"Onto" is fine in normal usage and implies connecting in general, and if you don't know which way round the threads are (i.e. which is outside). In technical documentaion / instructions I would stick to "into" if this is actually correct (e.g. as it is in your graphic).

Comment: also I'm assuming "pile" is a simple typo. Just checking as you've done it more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays "male" and "female" threads are being called "external" and "internal" threads, respectively. The designations are changing in catalogs and technical documents.

If both pieces are freestanding, they are **screwed together**.

If the piece with the male/external  thread is stationary, the piece with the female/internal thread is **screwed** or **threaded** *onto* it.

If the piece with the female/internal thread is stationary, the piece with the male/external thread is screwed or threaded *into* it.